# Show image gallery from a custom field

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, tinymce

I have a custom field in a custom post type. The custom field is a tinymce editor and I should echo out what user enters on it. If user enters text it is shown as well but when an image or a gallery is inserted the output is:

```
[gallery ids="221,207"]
```

here is my code:

```
$content  = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'company-catalog', true);
    if(isset($content) && !empty($content)){?>
        <h2>Catalog</h2>
        <div class="company-tech"><?php echo $content;  ?></div>
    <?php } ?>
```

how can I force wp to show image gallery or single image instead of image code?

Comment: I could show gallery with do_shortcode() but I am not sure is right way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$content  = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'company-catalog', true);
    if(isset($content) && !empty($content)){?>
        <h2>Catalog</h2>
        <div class="company-tech"><img src="<?php echo $content;  ?>" /></div>
    <?php } ?>
```

img src tag added.

Comment: As I told the output of $content is something like: `[gallery ids="221,207"]` . It can not be used like this.

Comment: sorry. i have not used tinymce.